# Hyperledger Composer - post on wallet/api return Error: Can't find end of central directory

Tags: angular, post, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to create a new user of my network through my angular application.
For this :

1. I add a user (username/password) on my database and log in this user to have an access token
2. I add the participant to my network

Angular code :

```
    return this.httpClient.post('http://<IP>:3001/participant", participant, {headers: this.httpHeadersAuth}).toPromise()
```

Node server code :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post("/participant", function(req, res) {
    const ParticipantAdd = require('composer-cli').Participant.Add;
    console.log(req.body)
    let newParticipant = '{ ' +
            '"$class": "vaccinspace.Parent",' +
            ' "idParent" : "' + req.body.idParent + '",' +
            ' "name" : "' + req.body.name + '",' +
            ' "surname" : "' + req.body.surname + '",' +
            ' "phone" : "' + req.body.phone + '",' +
            ' "email" : "' + req.body.email +
            ' "}';
    console.log(newParticipant)
   let options = {
      card: 'admin@vaccin-network',
      data: newParticipant
    };
    ParticipantAdd.handler(options)
      .then((response) => {
          res.json({
               message: response,
               idUser:  newParticipant.idParent
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          res.status(401).json({
            message: error
          });
      });
});
```

3. I add the identity issue on my network and recover my card

Angular code :

```
const identity = '{ ' +
              '"participant": "resource:vaccinspace.Parent#' + user['id'] + '",' +
              '"userID" : "' + user['id'] +
              '"}';
          return this.httpClient.post(this.URLAuth + "identity", identity, {responseType: 'blob',headers: this.httpHeadersAuth}).toPromise()
```

Node server code :

```
app.post("/identity", function(req, res) {
    const IdCard                    = require('composer-common').IdCard;
    const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;
    const AdminConnection           = require('composer-admin').AdminConnection;
    const CardExport                = require('composer-cli').Card.Export;
    const ParticipantAdd = require('composer-cli').Participant.Add;


    let businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
    const adminConnection         = new AdminConnection();

    var cardName;
    const participant = req.body.participant;
    const userID = req.body.userID;
        return businessNetworkConnection.connect('admin@vaccin-network')
        .then(() => {
                // Create a new identity for user
                return businessNetworkConnection.issueIdentity(participant, userID)
        })
        .then((identity) => {
                // Create and import card
                const metadata = {
                    userName: identity.userID,
                    version: 1,
                    enrollmentSecret: identity.userSecret,
                    role: "parent",
                    businessNetwork: "vaccin-network"
                };
                cardName = metadata.role + metadata.userName + "@" + metadata.businessNetwork
                const connectionProfile = {...}
              const card = new IdCard(metadata, connectionProfile);
              return adminConnection.importCard(cardName, card)
        })
        .then(() => {
            return adminConnection.exportCard(cardName);
        })
        .then((response) => {
                        res.type('binary');
                        res.send(response)
        })
        .then(() => {
            //Se déconnecter
            businessNetworkConnection.disconnect()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(401).json({
                        message: error
            });
        });
});
```

4. I post-transform card data to file and post it on `/api/wallet/import?=<name>`

Angular code : ("card data" is return by creating of identity)

```
const file = new File([cardData], user['id'] + '.card', {
                  type: 'application/octet-stream',
                  lastModified: Date.now()
              });

              const formData = new FormData();
              formData.append('card', file);
              const headers = new HttpHeaders();
              headers.set('Authorization', this.CookieService.get('access_token').split(':')[1].split('.')[0]);
              return this.httpClient.post('https://<IP>:3000/api/wallet/import?name=' + user['id'], formData, {withCredentials: true,headers}).toPromise();
          })
```

But this post doesn't work and I have this error on my rest server logs :

> Unhandled error for request POST /api/wallet/import?name=9d...: Error:
>   Can't find the end of the central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is,
>   see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html

Someone have an idea about how fixe this ?
For information : card is created (i can see it with "composer card list")
i exported this card (with "composer card export....). And i posted this card : 
- on composer rest server api 
- with postman (same paramaters than my angular post) 
and this worked fine !

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

You need add the Content Type to the header request, with multipart/formdata.

Good luck.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this error, I have the same error.

Comment: I think this post should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I didn't achieve to import my card like this. I resolved my issu by creating a card file save on my server, importing it on and deleting this file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar sort of problem, which was happening because the base64 column of the Card table in my loopback wallet database (MySQL) was too small. autoupdate had converted the field to VARCHAR(512) and the data was being truncated. I increased the column to VARCHAR(2048) and it fixed the problem.